# using portable git with pythongit

Tags: python-3.x, git, gitpython

I downloaded portable git from here: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.22.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.22.0-64-bit.7z.exe

and then I installed it to `C:\\Programs\\Git`

I installed git python by running `pip install gitpython`. My problem is when I import git
I get this error

```
>>> import git
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\26099\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\git\__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    refresh()
  File "C:\Users\26099\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\git\__init__.py", line 73, in refresh
    if not Git.refresh(path=path):
  File "C:\Users\26099\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py", line 290, in refresh
    raise ImportError(err)
ImportError: Bad git executable.
The git executable must be specified in one of the following ways:
    - be included in your $PATH
    - be set via $GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE
    - explicitly set via git.refresh()

All git commands will error until this is rectified.

This initial warning can be silenced or aggravated in the future by setting the
$GIT_PYTHON_REFRESH environment variable. Use one of the following values:
    - quiet|q|silence|s|none|n|0: for no warning or exception
    - warn|w|warning|1: for a printed warning
    - error|e|raise|r|2: for a raised exception

Example:
    export GIT_PYTHON_REFRESH=quiet


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\26099\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\git\__init__.py", line 85, in <module>
    raise ImportError('Failed to initialize: {0}'.format(exc))
ImportError: Failed to initialize: Bad git executable.
The git executable must be specified in one of the following ways:
    - be included in your $PATH
    - be set via $GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE
    - explicitly set via git.refresh()

All git commands will error until this is rectified.

This initial warning can be silenced or aggravated in the future by setting the
$GIT_PYTHON_REFRESH environment variable. Use one of the following values:
    - quiet|q|silence|s|none|n|0: for no warning or exception
    - warn|w|warning|1: for a printed warning
    - error|e|raise|r|2: for a raised exception

Example:
    export GIT_PYTHON_REFRESH=quiet
```

I know that it is because it cant find git. the error says i can tell pythongit where it is but I am not sure how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Portable Git seems not to import the directory of `git` executable into the environment variable `Path` automatically (you can type `git` in Command Prompt or Powershell to check).

Therefore, to ensure python git to be able to find `git`, you can either

- add the path in which the `git` executable is located (in this case maybe `C:\Programs\Git\bin`) to the `Path` variable

or

- set the value of environment variable `GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE` to the path of `git` executable (in this case maybe `C:\Programs\Git\bin\git.exe`).

Hope it helps.

Comment: How would I set the enviroment variable. would I open a terminal and type set GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE=C:\Programs\Git\bin\git.exe

Comment: @Dextron You can set the environment variable in several ways:

1. You can press Windows key, type to search `environment variable` and open the dialog to set environment variables;

2. You can also use command `setx` in your terminal to set environment variables. To set the `GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE`, you may want to type `setx GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE C:\Programs\Git\bin\git.exe`.